# Azure DevOps (VSTS / TFS) - Add discussion through OData/API

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, odata, devops

I want to add a discussion item to a WorkItem using Javascript.
Based on the [MS-REST/API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), and the exact example shown there, I tried the following;

```
var lURL = "https://dev.azure.com/XXXX/XXXX/_apis/wit/workItems/1297985/comments?api-version=5.1-preview.3"; 
var jsonObj = [ { "text": "test discussion comments" } ];
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
      $.ajax({
         url: lURL,
             headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + MyVerySecretKey)
             },
             type: 'PATCH',
         contentType: 'application/json-patch+json', 
         data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
         cache: false,
         dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(results) 
    {
        console.log("Saved to Azure DevOps!");
    }
    ); 
  });
```

This, unfortunately, leads to a 405 error(Method not allowed).
Can anyone help me move forward? Where did I make a mistake?

thanks,
Joost

Answer (score 0):

That can be the type of your request. You are using `type: 'PATCH'`. However, the sample page contains POST:

> **POST** https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/workItems/299/comments?api-version=5.1-preview.3

PATCH is used to update an existing comment.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution (also thanks to @Shamrai);

I changed
var jsonObj = [ { "text": "test discussion comments" } ];
to
var jsonObj = { "text": "test discussion comments" };

Changed 
type: 'PATCH',
to
type: 'POST',

And changed 
contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
to
contentType: 'application/json',

all working now!